# Find complexity of the following recurrence: T(n) = T(n/2) + log(n)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

How can I estimate the run time of two loops, where each runs in a logarithmic time, as shown here:

```
for(int i=n; i>=0; i /= 2)
{
    for( int j=i; j>=0; j /= 2)
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```

My analysis:

```
i = n  , 1  => j = lg n  | 1+lg (n) 
i = n/2, 1  => j = lg n/2 | 1+lg (n/2)
i = 1  , 1  => j = 0      | 1
```

How to sum up the logarithmic term in this case?

Comment: Your Question title and description not clear please elaborate more and update your title.

Comment: @CodeChanger now? is it clear?

Comment: Great Now its look clear and answerable.

Comment: Just a note. Both loops are infinite...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
i = n.      | Inner loop runs log(n) iterations.       | O(log(n))
i = n/2.    | Inner loop runs log(n/2) iterations.     | O(log(n))
i = n/4.    | Inner loop runs log(n/4) iterations.     | O(log(n))
.           |                                          |
.           |                                          |
i = log(n). | Inner loop runs log(log(n)) iterations.  | O(log(log(n)))
```

What are we noticing ? that for each `n` we are adding `O(log(n))`

This recurrence is `T(n) = T(n/2) + log(n) + 1`
Which can be expanded the following way:

```
T(n) = log(n) + log(n/2) + log(n/4) + ... + 1
     = log(n) + [log(n)-1] + [log(n)-2] + [log(n) - 3] + .... + 1
     = log(n)*log(n) - (2 + 3 + .... log(n))
     = log(n)*log(n) - ([(2+log(n))*log(n)]/2) 
     = log(n)*log(n) - ~0.5log(n)*log(n)
     = ~0.5log(n)*log(n)

T(n) = O(log(n)*log(n))
```